# How to get TCP state of connection?

Tags: java, network-programming, intrusion-detection

I use JPcap to capture packets. I don't know how to get TCP state of connection flags through these captured packet ?

```
Ex: OTH, REJ, RSTO, RSTOS0, RSTR, S0, S1, S2, S3, SF, SH
```

I am building Intrusion detection System.?

At present extracting attributes of KDD CUP 99 Dataset for live system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "OTH, REJ, RSTO, RSTOS0, RSTR, S0, S1, S2, S3, SF, SH" are, but the only things in a TCP segment that affect the state of the connection are the TCP control bits SYN, ACK, FIN, and RST. See [#3.4 of RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) &ff. for a complete description.